# How to embed GLFW window in to WinAPI window frame?

Tags: c++, winapi, glfw

I have the following working code, which attaches the OpenGL handle to an existing WinAPI window. It works fine and I can properly get the properties (height and width for example) of the WinAPI dialog through calling openGL *glfwGetWindowSize(glfwWnd, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);* function.

```
LPCTSTR WindowName = "Untitled - Notepad";
    
HWND hwnd = FindWindow("Notepad", WindowName);  

        if (!glfwInit()) {
            return -1;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

        GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);

        GLFWwindow* glfwWnd = glfwAttachWin32Window(hwnd, window);

        GLint windowWidth, windowHeight;
        glfwGetWindowSize(glfwWnd, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
```

But what I actually want is for window "My Title" to be embedded inside the Notepad window frame. Which is not happening as they are still two separate windows. Any way of achieving this?

Comment: *"Any way of achieving this?"* - No. [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) explains, why.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Out of interest, what if I was able to create an OpenGL context in Notepad and then pass the handle to my program, would it work that way? I mean, it shouldn't matter much if the parent window belongs to another process as all I want is to manipulate the context in the standard way.

Comment: The moment you create a window hierarchy that crosses threads you have to `1` have full control over both threads, and `2` absolutely know what you're doing. If one of the windows is owned by Notepad then you do not have control over both threads.